# Howto start gvim with a maximized window from a bash-script in gnome

Tags: vim, gnome

I want to write a bash-script that starts a gvim-session directly in a maximized window.

That is my bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash - 
set -o nounset

cd /home/alexthebird/vim-stuff; # directory of the gvim-session file
gvim -S bootmap;                # start gvim from the sessionfile 'bootmap'
```

Do you have any ideas how to accomplish this with a bashscript? Gvim should only be maximized when it is started over this script. Any other ideas how to accomplish this are welcome, of course.

I use Ubuntu 11.04 with gnome.

Thank you for taking the time to read my message.

AlexTheBird

**This script works:**

```
#!/bin/bash - 
set -o nounset
# directory of the gvim-session file
cd /home/alexthebird/vim-stuff;
# -f because of a ubuntu global-menu bug
# -S starts from session-file named 'bootmap'
# -geom solved the problem. see post of Lstor
gvim -geom '200x50+0+0' -f -S bootmap; # start gvim from the sessionfile 'bootmap';
```

Thank you all for your time.

**EDIT :** I just found out that the above solution **only works for the unity-2d (non 3D accelerated) desktop**. Which is fine for me. It does not work with the default Ubuntu-desktop which uses the 3D accelerated version of Unity.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what part is not working with your current script.

Comment: The script is working. My problem is that I don't know how to start gvim with a maximized window from this script. So that I don't have to maximize the gvim-window afterwards.

Comment: By the way, this question would get better answers in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the -geom(etry) option to match the size with the size of your monitor(s).

```
gvim -geom 200x50+0+0
```

Where `200` is the number of characters you can fit horizontally, `50` is the same vertically, and `+0+0` indicates zero horizontal and vertical offset from the top-left corner of the screen.

Note that the window would not be maximized per se, it would only be (approximately) the same size as your display.

Comment: You could also add this to your vimrc: `autocmd GUIEnter * winpos 0 0 | set lines=50 columns=200` or you can call `gvim -c 'winpos 0 0 | set lines=50 columns=200'`

Comment: I can't believe it. I was going to type "No, I want the windows maximized" but the -geom option actually had the same effect on the unity-interface. The upper window border disappears and close/min/max buttons join to the global-menu. Thanks!

Comment: I meant the window title bar disappears in the last sentence ... sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me on Ubuntu 8.04, Gnome (based on comments on [this forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1124561)):

```
#!/bin/bash
gvim

sleep 1  # give gvim time to launch

wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

You may need to install `wmctrl`:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Comment: Thank you Curt but this doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 11.04. Because of a bug in the global-menu from Ubuntu, i am not able to use the the Menu bar from gvim when I am starting it without the -f switch.

Comment: The -f switch from gvim, makes it a foreground process, so sleep and wmctrl only gets executed when i close gvim.

Comment: And here is the link to the bug I am talking about.
[link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/770271)

Answer (score 0):

like @Curt Nelson , I use `wmctrl`, with with `autocmd` and `guienter`.  It works both on my windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10.

1. Install wmctrl: `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`
2. add the following script to your config.

script:

```
if has("gui_running")
    if MySys() == 'linux'
        autocmd GUIEnter * silent !wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
    else
        winpos 0 0
        set lines=99999 columns=99999
        autocmd guienter * let &columns = 999 | let &columns = &columns/2 
        autocmd guienter * set lines=9999 columns=9999
    endif
endif
```